# IONIC FCM push notification ios , not able to receive

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am trying to using firebase push notification for IONIC 1. I am able to do it successfully in android. But in iOS i am able to add the FCM plugin and build it successfully.  While opening the mobile app it ask for push notification permissions also.

But, when i try to send from the firebase notification. I am not able to receive notification in mobile.I have added the .plist to the project root directory and build it.

Do i need to do any configuration  for IONIC 1 iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Enable Push Notification in capabilities in XCode if your are using XCode 8 or higher.

[Followings from Ionic site](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#setup)

> **Note for users of Xcode 8 and higher.**
>
> If you're using the latest version of Xcode, you will likely need to activate  the Push Notifications capability before your app is able to receive notifications.
>
> To do this, simply navigate to the Capabilities section in your app's overview within Xcode and toggle Push Notifications, as seen below.

[image]